# How to check for that map is containg the particular key using thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using the `thymeleaf` for presentation layer, so from controller i am sending the map containing key and list of values like this `Map<Long,List<Long>>` to  x.html. But how i  check  whether the key contained in map in  x.html using thymeleaf so please tell me the way to check it

i tried this way but not successfull

```
<span th:if="${#maps.containsKey(myMap, myStringValue)}">YEAH!</span>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such method you described since Thymeleaf version 1.0 which works for me as expected (see [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#maps)). Maybe your `Map` key isn't `String` value or `myStringValue` isn't `String`.

Did you tried use constant `String` as key?

```
<span th:if="${#maps.containsKey(myMap, 'valueOfMyStringValue')}">YEAH!</span>
```

Or call `Map#containsKey` method directly on `Map`?

```
<span th:if="${myMap.containsKey('valueOfMyStringValue')}">YEAH!</span>
```