# Thymeleaf: th:value - if property exists

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to create a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${map.version} name="version"/>
```

**Problem:**
`version` maybe a **non existing** attribute yet (I am not talking about  null!).
Right now I am getting an Exception `Property or field 'version' cannot be found on object`

**What I need:**
If it does not exist, th:value statement maybe ignored or tag removed

**CLARIFICATION:**
`map` comes from Spring Controller in a handler-method:

```
@PostMapping("/new")
public String handleMapFormSubmit(
    @ModelAttribute("map") @Valid AddMapCommand command, BindingResult result ) {

    if ( result.hasErrors() ) {
        return "map-form";
    }

    // do some stuff

    return ".....";
}
```

Problem is that `map` (AddMapCommmand) in this handler-method **does not contain** the `version` attribute. In another handler-method (UpdateMapCommand) it does. The whole point is to **reuse** the `map-form` thymeleaf template in both scenarios which are almost similar.

Comment: is `version` a key to the map that you're adding?  If so, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621301/how-to-use-map-getkey-in-thymeleaf-broadleaf-ecom

Comment: yes it is. but it can exist or not exist. I will look at the link thanks.

Comment: I have tried `${map['version']}`. It works, when the version is set but throws an Exception if not.

Comment: well, ok then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559367/how-to-check-for-that-map-is-containg-the-particular-key-using-thymleaf

Comment: map in my case is not a map (HashMap) but a GameMap, a own domain type with attributes in it (one of them is version)

Comment: I tried your link but get Exception :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `instanceof` operator to be used only for the object that contains the property:

```
<input type="hidden" 
 th:if="${map instanceof T(my.project.UpdateMapCommand)}" 
 th:value="${map.version} name="version">
```

For future reference, it is **extremely** confusing using a variable like `map` and not have the reader interpret it as a `java.util.Map`. You should change your `map` variable name to make it less confusing, or at least for the purpose of asking the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: that pointed me to the right direction. thanks. I agree for the map naming. I was just in a hurry. cheers anyways!

Comment: Is there anything in Thymeleaf like: object.hasAttribute('version') ?